# Show a document with default application from an App in a OSX 10.8 sandbox

Tags: objective-c, sandbox, osx-mountain-lion

I wrote a download manager for OSX 10.8 with enabled sandbox.

after downloading a file the app will start that file with the default application for that file type.

I try to do that this simple way:

> [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:file];
>
> "file" is a NSString and points to
>   /Users/philipp/Library/Containers/com.philipp.downloader/Data/Downloads/Test
>   mp3.mp3

iTunes jumping in my dock for a while, but buttom line nothing happens.

What is the problem and how do I do it right?

---

EDIT:

The problem is that iTunes has no permissions to read *Test mp3.mp3*.
I Found this message in my *system.log*:

> CoreServicesUIAgent[89712]: Quarantine resolution refused to pid 87288
>   because it is not allowed to read /Users/philipp/Downloads/Test
>   mp3.mp3

The final question is: how can I set the correct permissions to that file?

Best greetings,

Philipp

Answer (score 0):

It either needs to be in your Sandboxed folder, or the user must explicitly open it. Otherwise, you have no access. I would suggest modifying your approach to perhaps have the user in some way select the MP3 files first, that way you have access to me. Just be sure to enable access for user selected files!